# Is there an 'easy' way to split an enormous HTML file into multiple pages

Tags: html, logging

I was given an html log file that has ~306K lines. I know there are better formats for this but would like to be able to view the file online. I think breaking the file up into smaller bits and "paging" is probably the way to go of any way other than manually doing the following:

- take header of initial page and copy to every new file
- copy 5-10k lines of the initial file and paste into a new body
- copy the footer of the initial file and copy to every new file

Then give basic naming conventions of 1.html, 2.html, 3.html and create sublinks on every page in the new footer.  Is there an automated way to do this?

Comment: You could parse the HTML and feed the log into a database, then view it with your own paginated viewer.

Comment: are you comfortable with java?

Comment: @EricLemos - unfortunately not at all.

Comment: @Ark - Javascript yes.

Comment: @WaleedKhan - DB is out of the question here for a number of reasons, not to mention I don't want to build a parser and handle this. It is a log of messages sent back and forth in conversation.

Comment: @JM4 What reasons? And fortunately, many general-purpose languages already have HTML parsers. In any case, it seems like a good usage case for a database.

Comment: @WaleedKhan - because it is a single project that will never be replicated again and I don't feel like creating a fairly complicated database based on the information contained within the file. I have sender / receiver information, timestamps, media files (audio, video, photo), etc to deal with. It isn't the cleanest but since the HTML file is already built. Reinventing the wheel just cut the file back down (essentially putting everything back into a database - I can't get access to the original anylonger) seems perhaps like that wrong way.

Comment: @jm4 i just give an answer, not sure its gonna totally help you, but you may find it usefull

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
 text = document.getElementById('text').value; var pieces = new Array(); var total = Math.ceil(text.length/10000); for(i=0;i<total;i++){
pieces[i] = text.substr(([i]*10000),10000)); }
```

then send it to a file(the way you want, ajax, or some write-txt)

Answer (score 1):

if your html file is properly formatted (i.e with line-breaks) you can take out the header and footer and split the content every let's say 1000 lines (or any amount that guarantees meaningful data). that sound's doable with a shell script.

Comment: This is probably the route I'll end up going. Thanks.

Comment: also if you're comfortable with javascript there's a [great module for node.js](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) that you can load jquery into and go about parsing very easily